# Question about rings homomorphism

Tags: ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

I need to prove the following result

> Let $p$ and $q$ be 2 different primes. There isn´t any homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to $\mathbb{Z}_q$ or from $\mathbb{Z}_q$ to $\mathbb{Z}_p$

What I've done:

Suppose that exists an homomorphism $f : \mathbb{Z_q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z_p} $ then $f (1) = 1$ so

$\underbrace{1+1+1\cdots+1\,}_\text{$q$ times} = \underbrace{f(1)+f(1)+f(1)\cdots +f(1)\,}_\text{$q$ times} = f(\underbrace{1+1+1\cdots +1\,}_\text{$q$ times})  = f(0) = 0$

So the left sum should be $0$ in $\mathbb{Z_p}$ but since $p \nmid q $ this is not true so we have a contradiction.

I think my proof isn´t correct because I've not used that $p$ and $q$ are primes, I've just used that they don´t divide to each other

Comment: "I think my proof isn´t correct because I've not used that $p$ and $q$ are primes, I've just used that they don´t divide to each other" - how would you know this from two arbitrary integers $m\neq n$ that they don' t divide each other? Take $3$ and $12$.

Comment: But what happen with cases like $q = 10$ and $p = 12$ ? These numbers don't divide to each other but they aren't primes

Comment: Yes, but we use a stronger assumption to conclude - that both are prime. Have a look at the question again: "Let $p$ and $q$ be two different primes". You said, we haven't used this. We have.

Comment: Ok  I understand it now, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, I'll denote by $0_k$ and $1_k$ the zero and unit element in $\mathbb{Z}_k$.

Your proof is actually correct. Indeed, you have
$$
q1_p=qf(1_q)=f(q1_q)=f(0_q)=0_p
$$
which is a contradiction, because it is known that $n1_k=0_k$ if and only if $k\mid n$.

You don't have used the “full force” of the hypothesis about $p$ and $q$ being primes and indeed it's not needed. The only fact needed in order to state that there is no ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_k\to\mathbb{Z}_h$ is that $k\nmid h$, with exactly the same argument:
$$
k1_h=kf(1_k)=f(k1_k)=f(0_k)=0_h
$$
which is impossible if $h\nmid k$.

Using primality would allow for a different proof. The image of $f\colon\mathbb{Z}_q\to\mathbb{Z}_p$ is an additive subgroup of the codomain having order a divisor of $q$. Thus the image can only have order $1$, so it cannot be a subring.

Comment: The OP *has* used that $p$ and $q$ are primesin the proof, namely the (weaker) implication that different primes don't divide each other.

Comment: @DietrichBurde The OP realized to not having used the *full force* of the two numbers being prime, so the question.